# Capturar elementos da tabela com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso fazer para pegar com o click elementos de uma tabela que esta sendo preenchida dinamicamente com jQuery? Eu quero que quando ela dor clicada fique marcada somente 1 linha da tabela. Eu consegui somente marcar todas.

Aqui quando clicar na tabela ele mostra um botão e agora eu queria para quando clicar na `td` ele marcar somente a que foi clicada e não todas

código:

```
$("#registros").click(function(){
  $("#excluir").toggle();
     $("tr").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Qual é o HTML?  o elemento `<table>` tem ID? qual é a parte dinamica? só o conteudo da tabela é dinamico ou a tabela também?

Comment: o conteudo da tabela e dinamico e o id da table em html e registros

Comment: Junta HTML para te poder ajudar. Precisas delegar esse evento, já há respostas parecidas com o que precisas.

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?

Comment: sim faz muito tempo

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizando o .on do jquery (http://api.jquery.com/on/), passando de um elemento que já exista no DOM como referencia, por ex:

```js
$('#elemento').on('click', '<identificador do elemento dinamico que será clicado', function(){
  // executa função
  });
```

```html
<div id="elemento">
<!-- aqui vai ser inserido o conteudo dinamico -->
</div>
```

Comment: n deu certo nao eu passei ali no elemnto o id da minha table ai dentro do identificador do elemento eu passei a tag <td> e coloquei minha funcao de marcar a td c ela fosse clicada mas nao rodou nao eu coloquei toda a funcao que vc passou do click dentro da minha e nao foi nao

Comment: mas a referencia não pode ser a tabela se ela for gerada dinamicamente.... faz um teste bem a grosso modo coloca o body como referencia.... mas você precisa localizar um wrapper mais próximo do elemento para referencia

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo correndo aqui, vê se isso te auxilia:

```js
$("table td").on('click', function(e){
  var linha = $(this).parent();
  if($(linha).hasClass("marcado"))
  {
    $(linha).removeClass("marcado");
    $(linha).css('background', "");
  }
  else
  {
    $(linha).addClass("marcado");
    $(linha).css('background', "gray");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
table td{
  border: solid 1px #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
    <td>Coluna</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```